# Comments under my answer disappeared automatically

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Well a couple of days back I answered this question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663857/redirect-to-view-from-ajax-call-on-error/30663979#30663979)** and there were lot of comments suggested to improve my answer which was accepted. Around 10-15 I can say. Comments of OP, one more user and mine too. But today when I saw the answer none of the comments existed. I just want to know what happened to the comments. Mod Deleted? and if yes why?

**I am just wondering because after I updated the answer I have just**
**mentioned one of the users name whose suggestion helped to improve the**
**quality of the answer**

But reason behind comment delete is still surprising me? Can anyone tell why this has happened?

Comment: Someone probably custom flagged your question and asked a moderator to clean up the comments.

Comment: @royhowie.. might be the possible thing, but all of them??

Comment: I did not mean that someone flagged each comment. I meant they flagged your question for a moderator and asked that the comments be cleansed. However, the answer given below is far more likely.

Comment: @royhowie Well that clarified your point Thanks anyways.

Comment: Regardless of the accepted answer, manual delete is always an option. Me personally I try to cleanup my own comments that were successful to get changes into a question or answer - based on meta questions that indicate this is a good thing to do.

Comment: @Gimby I second you but I was thinking comments might be useful someday if its not reflected in answer of question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SE software raised a "More than 20 comments posted in the last n days" flag, which a moderator handled by purging the comments.

Most of the comments were either "thanks," or clarification comments.  Clarification comments should generally be folded into the answer, which is apparently what happened, since the answer appears to contain *two different versions of code* based on comment feedback. That's not the ideal way to do it, but that's the way it was done here.

It's been said before, but bears repeating here: comments are *temporary, post-it notes.*  Their sole purpose is clarification, and once that purpose has been served, they're no longer needed.

Comment: Seems Legit.. Doubts cleared.